# Is there a way to get access to the Ember model within a nested view?

Tags: ember.js, coffeescript, ember-data

I'm trying to get access to the model for an ember model object that I'm currently editing. I'm rendering a view:

```
    {{view App.RemarkTextField valueBinding="content"}}
```

And here's the view:

```
    App.RemarkTextField = Ember.TextField.extend
      focusOut: (evt) ->
        @state = @_context.get("stateManager.currentState")
        if (@state.name == "saved")
          @rollback()

      keyUp: (evt) ->
        @rollback() if evt.keyCode == 27

      rollback: ->
        @._context.transaction.rollback()
        @get('parentView').intoReadMode()
```

I'm calling intoReadMode() on the parent view to exit editing mode on focus lost or escape, which reverts from an input to standard text.

This code is functioning correctly, but it feels dirty to call this._context to get access to the ember model and its current state. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Agreed calling `this._context` is a sign that something is not quite right. In this case you would be better off accessing the model via the controller.

```
App.RemarkTextField = Ember.TextField.extend({
  focusOut: function(evt) {
    console.log('controller', this.get('controller'));
    var state = this.get("controller.stateManager.currentState.name");
    console.log('state', state);  
  }
});
```

FWIW it probably makes sense to move model access and rollback method into the controller. Then refactor the parentView so that it enters/exits readonly mode based on a property of the controller.

```
App.RemarkTextField = Ember.TextField.extend({
  focusOut: function(evt) {
    this.get('controller').send('rollback');
  },
  keyUp: function() {
    if (evt.keyCode == 27) {
      this.get('controller').send('rollback');
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: The problem here is that the controller does not have a stateManager object.

Comment: @Faun I am assuming controller is an ObjectController (so it should proxy to the model) and that the model has a stateManager. Is that not the case? Also assume you would define a "rollback" method on controller. Controller will have access to current transaction/model and can rollback tx as needed.